# Problem with install USB WiFi ASUS USB-AC51 [Mediatek MT7610/Ralink RT2870]

Tags: drivers, usb, mediatek

I've tried to to install Mediatek MT7610/Ralink RT2870 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-79-generic x86_64) without any results :(

1.Plug this USB dongle in PC.

```
root@hp:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:17d1 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AC51 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Mediatek MT7610/Ralink RT2870]
```

2.Download from Mediatek last driver https://d86o2zu8ugzlg.cloudfront.net/mediatek-craft/drivers/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2 , extracted the archive and:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

3. After reboot I have next results:

```
root@hp:~# lsmod | grep mt
mt7650u_sta           913408  0

root@hp:~# modinfo mt7650u_sta
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-79-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mt7650u_sta.ko
version:        3.0.0.2
description:    RT2870 Wireless Lan Linux Driver
author:         Paul Lin <paul_lin@ralinktech.com>
license:        GPL
srcversion:     3B2050BC166EF1626C89197
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7650d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc02ipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7630d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc02ipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp7610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp7610d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:
vermagic:       4.4.0-79-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)

root@hp:~# dmesg | grep mt76
[  116.021853] mt7650u_sta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

root@hp:~# dmesg | grep rt28
[  116.023699] rtusb init rt2870 --->
[  116.023732] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870

root@hp:~# ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:2d:02:54:b0
          inet addr:192.168.150.10  Bcast:192.168.150.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:2dff:fe02:54b0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:171286 (171.2 KB)  TX bytes:266297 (266.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

root@hp:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

I don't understand what's the problem and how do I install this driver?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a regression in 4.4.0-79 compared to 4.4.0-78, and therefore the dongle is recognized only when hotplugged, and will not work after a reboot. With the older kernel everything is fine and dandy out of the box, alas a kernel downgrade on Mint 18.1 solved it.  Upgrading to 4.4.0-79 is of low urgency anyway. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Linux Kernel 4.19, the Asus USB-AC51 is supported.

See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/usb.c#L30

You might wanna give it a try.

> (Try install all the following debian packages:
>   linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
>    linux-modules-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
>    from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/ )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right version of driver, downloaded from Myria-de Git.

```
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
```

In this version was added support many devices on this type of chip (including ASUS USB-AC51).

```
USB_DEVICE_ID rtusb_dev_id[] = {

{USB_DEVICE(0x148F,0x7610)}, /* MT7610U Ralink VID */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0E8D,0x7610)}, /* MT7610U MediaTek VID / Sabrent NTWLAC */
{USB_DEVICE(0x13B1,0x003E)}, /* Cisco Linksys AE6000 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x7392,0xA711)}, /* Edimax 7711ULC/7711MAC */
{USB_DEVICE(0x7392,0xB711)}, /* Elecom WDC-433SU2M */
{USB_DEVICE(0x148F,0x761A)}, /* TP-LINK Archer T2UH */
{USB_DEVICE(0x148F,0x760A)}, /* TP-LINK */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0B05,0x17D1)}, /* ASUS USB-AC51 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0B05,0x17DB)}, /* ASUS USB-AC50 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0DF6,0x0075)}, /* Edimax EW-7811UTC AC600 / Sitecom WLA-3100 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x2001,0x3D02)}, /* D-Link DWA-171 rev B1 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0586,0x3425)}, /* ZyXEL NWD6505 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x07B8,0x7610)}, /* AboCom AU7212 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x04BB,0x0951)}, /* IO DATA WN-AC433UK */
{USB_DEVICE(0x057C,0x8502)}, /* AVM FRITZ!WLAN USB Stick AC 430 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x293C,0x5702)}, /* Comcast Xfinity KXW02AAA */
{USB_DEVICE(0x2019,0xAB31)}, /* Planex GW-450D/GW-450D-KATANA */
{USB_DEVICE(0x20F4,0x806B)}, /* TRENDnet TEW-806UBH AC600 */
```

Comment: But not for arm platform or more special beagle bone black with debian.